QCD parton shower hard scale
Currently I'm studying parton showers from QCD and I'm having trouble with understanding how the hard scale $Q$ is related to the virtuality and energy of the parent parton. The Sudakov factor $\Delta(Q, p_\mathrm{T})$ gives you the probability of finding no emitted partons between the scales $Q$ and $p_\mathrm{T}$ (instead of $p_\mathrm{T}$, you could also choose other quantities, but in this context $p_\mathrm{T}$ is used). The Sudakov factor for quark-quark splitting is given by
$$ \Delta(Q, p_\mathrm{T}) = \exp\mathopen{}\left[-\dfrac{\alpha_\mathrm{s}}{2\pi}\int\limits_{p_\mathrm{T}^2}^{Q^2}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} t}{t}\int\limits_{z_{\text{min}}}^{z_{\text{max}}} P_{qq}(z)\mathrm{d} z\right]\mathclose{},$$
where $P_{qq}(z)$ is the splitting function for quark-quark splitting and $z$ is the fraction of the parent quark energy carried by the daughter quark. Now consider a quark splitting into a gluon and a quark. My main questions are about the integration boundaries $z_\mathrm{min}$ and $z_\mathrm{max}$.

In class we derived that for a light-like parent parton with $p^\mu = (E, 0, 0, E)$, the daughter partons (approximated to be light-like as well) have four-momenta $(zE, p_\mathrm{T}, 0, \sqrt{z^2E^2-p_\mathrm{T}^2})$ and the same for the other but then with $z \to 1-z$ and $p_\mathrm{T} \to -p_\mathrm{T}$. Then $z_{\text{min}}$ and $z_{\text{max}}$ are derived from the constraint that the $z$-component of the daughter's momenta should be real. In that case, you get that $z_{\text{min}} = 1 - z_{\text{max}} = \sqrt{p_\mathrm{T}^2/E^2}$. The result should be $z_{\text{min}} = \sqrt{p_\mathrm{T}^2/Q^2}$ where $Q$ is this "hard scale" (see the QFT book by Schwartz, page 684). Then I might imagine that you could say that the initial parton has four-momentum $(Q, 0, 0, Q)$ and everything is alright. However...

$Q^2$ is also the virtuality of the initial parton (i.e. $p^2 = Q^2$). If you would say that the parent parton has four-momentum $(Q, 0, 0, Q)$ then it has a virtuality of zero. The virtuality seems to be unrelated to the energy to me.


In a real parton shower, it is true that you start with a time-like parton which becomes less virtual as the shower evolves (so the light-like four-momenta is just an approximation for kinematics). So my questions are:

How does $Q^2$ put a limit to $z_{\text{min}}$, rather than the initial parton's energy?
If the derivation for $z_{\text{min}}$ and $z_{\text{max}}$ are indeed correct, then why are you allowed to assume all partons to be light-like?

